# Java: can't get readline() to work

Tags: java, input, io

I am trying to parse some input test cases for a competitive programming problem, but the program just sits and waits even though I am reading the entire line and the "\n" character.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String result = "", input = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
        result += input;   
    }
    System.out.print(result);
}
```

This is super-simplified, but it still doesn't work. When I enter (without quotes)
 "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and then press enter, it just waits for more input. How can I make it work so that after I press enter, the programs leaves the while loop?

Can I make this work for multiple lines as well? For instance, after the last "\n", if there are no more characters, then break out of the loop.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Why do you need a while loop ?

Comment: This is 2016. Why don't you use try-with-resources?

Comment: I want to input a variable number of lines.

Comment: Oooh, I've never heard of try-with-resources, let me check it out.

Comment: Dude after you press `enter`, `Ctrl + Z` on windows, `Ctrl + D` on Linux, `Cmd + D` on Mac

Comment: Wow, `Cmd + D` actually worked. What is it doing to make it work?

Comment: @Misha, that's the signal to the OS that the input stream has reached the end. I.e. nothing to see here, move on

Comment: Another way to do it without using `cmd + d` is to do `java myprogram <<< "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"` Or put the string `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` in a file call `myprogram.in` then do `java myprogram < \`cat myprogram.in\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you press `enter`, `ctrl + z` on windows, `ctrl + d` on Linux, or `cmd + d` on Mac.

These keyboard shortcuts are used in their respective Os's to signal EOF to the OS which will in turn notify the jvm.

Another way to do it without using `cmd + d` is to do `java myprogram <<< "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"` Or put the string in a file call `myprogram.in` then do `` java myprogram < `cat myprogram.in` ``

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `readLine()` once. You have it in a loop. If you call it one time, it should read one line.

Here is the documentation on `readLine()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

It statues that it will return `null` only if the end of stream is reached. As you are using `System.in` as your input stream, you will not reach the end of it just by pressing enter.

Comment: Thank you for helping me realize that I can end the `System.in` input stream by just pressing enter

Comment: @Misha No you can't. You can end it be typing Ctrl/d or Ctrl/z depending on your system. Enter only terminates a single line.

Comment: Sorry. Typo, I meant can't